# Clear empty url params

Tags: php

Hello stackoverflow community, I need help with `GET` stuff. So I've got advanced search, and when I submit form, browser shows this link:

> /page_korteles.php?kriterijus-susirgo-nuo=&kriterijus-susirgo-iki=&kriterijus-gimimo-nuo=&kriterijus-gimimo-iki=&kriterijus-isdavimo-nuo=&kriterijus-isdavimo-iki=&kriterijus-ivedimo-nuo=&kriterijus-ivedimo-iki=&kriterijus-isplestinis=ne

Is it possible to clear empty parameters? Or maybe there is different way to work with this? Really need some ideas.

Comment: If you just want to remove them from get, take a look at [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: `print_r(array_filter($_GET));`

Comment: Is it possible to land that function before showing in url? Or should i land it onload and redirect immediately?

Comment: @Sidas, that function will not remove things from url, just from the variable

Comment: Why you need it? Does it create some problems for you?

Comment: @VladimirKovpak well link would look much sexier then with empty params

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `array_filter()`:-

```
print_r(array_filter($_GET));
```

More knowledge:-  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Note:- The above function will not remove anything from your url, just remove empty value elements from the array variable `$_GET`.

Maybe you want something like below (this suggestion given by another persone, i am just adding it because may be it helpful for you):-

```
if(array_filter($_GET) == $_GET) { //stays on page and do other stuff (already removed empty) }else{ // remove empty keys and redirect to url without them; }
```

Comment: Is it possible to land that function before showing in url? Or should i land it onload and redirect immediately?

Comment: Could do something like this(untested): `if(array_filter($_GET) == $_GET) { //stays on page  and do other stuff (already removed empty) }else{ // remove empty keys and redirect to url without them; }`. That check should prevent loops...

Comment: I didn't think of it before, but keep in mind that if the value is `0` (and 0 is also expected), it will be removed from the array too.

Answer (score 3):

If you actually want the URL to look not include the empty parameters, you can redirect to the same page after filtering them out of the query string.

```
// using a callback in array_filter can avoid filtering non-empty falsey values (0, etc.)
$not_blank = array_filter($_GET, function($x) { return $x != ''; });

if ($not_blank != $_GET) {
    $query = http_build_query($not_blank);
    header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?$query") ;
    exit;
}
```

Honestly, though, I don't see how it hurts anything to have them there. It seems to be adding an unnecessary extra step and it may cause problems in the future if you actually need to send an empty parameter value to the page.

Comment: It helped me building canonical url and preventing duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

try something like this when submitting form

```
  $("#search-form").submit(function(){
    $("input").each(function(index, input){
        if($(input).val() == "") {
            $(input).remove();
        }
    });
  });
```

Comment: i like this idea, but i think better create array with not empty values and send this array to server and don't remove elements...